# How to center content over several panels with MigLayout?

Tags: java, centering, miglayout

I have a large panel, that contains 3 smaller panels (`locationPanel`, `usagePanel`, `structuralAspectsPanel`).

Each of the smaller panels has some `JLabels` and `JCheckBoxes` on them. I went ahead and centered the components on each panel, but how can I accomplish the center them over all 3 panels? (see the black line in the center please)

I have tried to use the cell-layout option in `MigLayout` (`new JLabel("Label here"), "cell 0 0")`, but was not able to create dynamically gaps of the same size, so that all components are centered. Using `gap 200` (180, 300, ...) to "push" the components into a visual center seems to work, but I want to refrain from using absolute positioning / gaps, since they might break easily.

I have attached a picture of my problem:
[image: How to center the components over several panels?]

Here is my source code:

```
public class RiskAssessmentPage extends JPanel {
  JPanel riskAssessmentPanel = new JPanel();

  JPanel locationPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel usagePanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel structuralAspectsPanel = new JPanel();

  public RiskAssessmentPage() {
    setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
    riskAssessmentPanel.setLayout(
        new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow, fill]", "[grow, fill, push][grow, fill, push][grow, fill, push]"));

    locationPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[grow, center][grow, left]"));
    locationPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Location"));

    usagePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[grow, center][grow, left]"));
    usagePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Usage"));

    structuralAspectsPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[grow, center][grow, left]"));
    structuralAspectsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Structural Aspects"));

    locationPanel.add(new JLabel("This is the first of all labels"));
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
    locationPanel.add(new JLabel("Second Label"));
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
    locationPanel.add(new JLabel("This Label is fairly large and long and pushes the text around"));
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");

    usagePanel.add(new JLabel("A label in the usage panel"));
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
    usagePanel.add(new JLabel("And another one and another one and another one"));
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");

    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JLabel("Label here"));
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JLabel("I am so uncreative with label names..."));
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JLabel("Thats it. I give up with naming them."));
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
    structuralAspectsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");

    riskAssessmentPanel.add(locationPanel);
    riskAssessmentPanel.add(usagePanel);
    riskAssessmentPanel.add(structuralAspectsPanel);

    add(riskAssessmentPanel, "grow, push");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your panels columns line up, you need to set them to the same size. In `MigLayout` you can do this by setting, in this case, the first column's **preferred size** and **growth rate** to be the same value you in all the panels. For example

```
panel1.new MigLayout("", //Unchanged Layout Constraints
        "[:500, grow, center][grow, left]", //Column Constraints
        ""); //Unchanged Row Constraints

panel2.new MigLayout("", //Unchanged Layout Constraints
        "[:500, grow, center][grow, left]", //Column Constraints
        ""); //Unchanged Row Constraints
```

In this example the preferred sizes of the first column of both `panel1` and `panel2` are set to 500 and the growth is set at its default value so that is also the same.

A working example of what is described can be seen here

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLay extends JFrame {

    private MigLay() {
        super("Button Layout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap", //Layout Constraints
        "grow, fill", //Column Constraints
        "grow, fill")); //Row Constraints
        createPanels();
        pack();
        setMinimumSize(getSize()); //Sets minimum size to the preferred size. Remove or change this line if you do not want that to happen
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanels() {

        JPanel locationPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel usagePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel structuralAspectsPanel = new JPanel();

        //JLabels for font metrics
        JLabel one = new JLabel("This is the first of all labels");
        JLabel two = new JLabel("Second Label");
        JLabel three = new JLabel("This Label is fairly large and long and pushes the text around");
        JLabel four = new JLabel("A label in the usage panel");
        JLabel five = new JLabel("And another one and another one and another one");

        //Font Metrics
        FontMetrics metrics = three.getFontMetrics(three.getFont()); //Take longest label manually or dynamically (You will have to add that code)
        int width = metrics.stringWidth(three.getText());

        locationPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[:" + width + ", grow, center][grow, left]"));
        locationPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Location"));

        usagePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[:" + width + ", grow, center][grow, left]"));
        usagePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Usage"));

        locationPanel.add(one);
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
        locationPanel.add(two);
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
        locationPanel.add(three);
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        locationPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");

        usagePanel.add(four);
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JSeparator(), "growx, span");
        usagePanel.add(five);
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");
        usagePanel.add(new JCheckBox("Checkbox with Label"), "skip, wrap");

        getContentPane().add(locationPanel);
        getContentPane().add(usagePanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigLay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out and it's actually quite simple!

Add `0:0, grow 60` to the first column and `grow 40` to the second one.

The `grow 60 / 40`-part means, that the left column get's 60% of the available width, while the other column gets 40%.

The `0:0`-part is about setting the minimal / preferred / maximal width (although I have to admit that I dont understand it completely, explanations welcome!...I've [opened a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682572/what-is-the-meaning-of-00-in-the-miglayout) just for this.).

Since all your panels get the same size on the left and right, they center at the same point.

```
locationPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[0:0, grow 60, center][grow 40, left]"));

usagePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[0:0, grow 60, center][grow 40, left]"));

structuralAspectsPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 2", "[0:0, grow 60, center][grow 40, left]"));
```